# create xml using data from excel using macro

Tags: xml, excel

Here is my requirement -
1) I have an xml and corresponding xsd document
2) It's a complex xml with multiple elements and their hierarchy. But there are only certain elements/fields that are important
3) I want to create an excel with these fields where user can enter data across multiple rows
4) When user clicks on create xml, separate xml should be created for each row
5) The xml created should contain all the elements (user entered + many more in original xml)

This is just a Sample-

```
<A>
   <A1/>
   <A2/>
</A>
<B>
   <B1>*User entered value*</B1>
   <B2>*User entered value*</B2>
</B>
<C>
   <C1/>
   <C2/>
</C>
```

I found some references on MSXML2.DOMDocument60 where one can create xml using this API and also validate against schema through excel macro. But in my case there are 1000s of tags. Below are some options I have in mind-

1. Use DOMDocument60 API and construct the xml line by line using macro. Since there are 1000s of tags, this approach would gulp 1000s of lines of code and that would make maintenance a cumbersome task !
2. Since I have sample xml, I can empty the existing values and then update the xml using the user entered value (get from excel cell data) through macro.  This seems more effective as it would save 1000s of lines of code, but is this possible ? Since the elements that needs to be updated are spread across xml, will I be able to search for an element and update only that element and not impact any other data/tag in the xml ?
3. Can anything be done with xsd ? None flashes to my mind with my requirement
4. Any other option ?

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base, you can use something like that:

```
Open "e:\0\xml.xml" For Input As #1
Open "e:\0\xml1.xml" For Output As #2

i = 1
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, aa

    If InStr(1, aa, "<B1>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        aa = Left(aa, 3 + InStr(1, aa, "<B1>", vbTextCompare)) & Cells(i, 1).Value & Right(aa, Len(aa) - InStr(1, aa, "</B1>", vbTextCompare) + 1)
        i = i + 1
    End If

    Print #2, aa
Wend

Close #1
Close #2
```

the code copy the original file, changing the text inside the tag B1 with the values in column A.
If you have more "pieces", you can merge different files...